# How to get started using mtpro2 lite on TeXLive?

Tags: fonts, texlive, mtpro

I want to use `mtpro2` but I have no idea how to get it working on TeXLive. I thought it was difficult to understand what do in order to install it. Until I became convinced that perhaps it is already installed on TeXLive, in which case I only need help to get started using it.

I have installed TeXLive to `/usr/local/texlive` . I suppose `mtpro2` is installed with texlive by default, since the line `\usepackage[lite,subscriptcorrection,slantedGreek,nofontinfo]{mtpro2}` doesnt induce an error.

This is my test document:

```
\documentclass[12pt,norsk,a4paper]{report}
\usepackage[utf8]{inputenc}
\usepackage[norsk]{babel}
\usepackage{amsfonts}
\usepackage{amssymb,amsmath,amsthm}
\usepackage[lite,subscriptcorrection,slantedGreek,nofontinfo]{mtpro2}
\begin{document}
Hello world!
$$
f^n(z) = \frac{n!}{2\pi\,i}\int_{\partial \Omega} \frac{f(\zeta)}{(\zeta - z)^{n+1}}\,{\rm d}\zeta
$$
\end{document}
```

This is what my error log outputs:

```
LOG FILE :
This is pdfTeX, Version 3.1415926-2.5-1.40.14 (TeX Live 2013) (format=pdflatex 2014.2.11) 30 AUG 2014 23:17
entering extended mode
restricted \write18 enabled.
%&-line parsing enabled.
**test.tex
(./test.tex
LaTeX2e <2011/06/27>
Babel <3.9h> and hyphenation patterns for 78 languages loaded.
(/usr/local/texlive/2013/texmf-dist/tex/latex/base/report.cls
Document Class: report 2007/10/19 v1.4h Standard LaTeX document class
(/usr/local/texlive/2013/texmf-dist/tex/latex/base/size12.clo
File: size12.clo 2007/10/19 v1.4h Standard LaTeX file (size option)
)
\c@part=\count79
\c@chapter=\count80
\c@section=\count81
\c@subsection=\count82
\c@subsubsection=\count83
\c@paragraph=\count84
\c@subparagraph=\count85
\c@figure=\count86
\c@table=\count87
\abovecaptionskip=\skip41
\belowcaptionskip=\skip42
\bibindent=\dimen102
)
(/usr/local/texlive/2013/texmf-dist/tex/latex/base/inputenc.sty
Package: inputenc 2008/03/30 v1.1d Input encoding file
\inpenc@prehook=\toks14
\inpenc@posthook=\toks15
(/usr/local/texlive/2013/texmf-dist/tex/latex/base/utf8.def
File: utf8.def 2008/04/05 v1.1m UTF-8 support for inputenc
Now handling font encoding OML ...
... no UTF-8 mapping file for font encoding OML
Now handling font encoding T1 ...
... processing UTF-8 mapping file for font encoding T1
(/usr/local/texlive/2013/texmf-dist/tex/latex/base/t1enc.dfu
File: t1enc.dfu 2008/04/05 v1.1m UTF-8 support for inputenc
defining Unicode char U+00A1 (decimal 161)
defining Unicode char U+00A3 (decimal 163)
defining Unicode char U+00AB (decimal 171)
defining Unicode char U+00BB (decimal 187)
defining Unicode char U+00BF (decimal 191)
defining Unicode char U+00C0 (decimal 192)
defining Unicode char U+00C1 (decimal 193)
defining Unicode char U+00C2 (decimal 194)
defining Unicode char U+00C3 (decimal 195)
defining Unicode char U+00C4 (decimal 196)
defining Unicode char U+00C5 (decimal 197)
defining Unicode char U+00C6 (decimal 198)
defining Unicode char U+00C7 (decimal 199)
defining Unicode char U+00C8 (decimal 200)
defining Unicode char U+00C9 (decimal 201)
defining Unicode char U+00CA (decimal 202)
defining Unicode char U+00CB (decimal 203)
defining Unicode char U+00CC (decimal 204)
defining Unicode char U+00CD (decimal 205)
defining Unicode char U+00CE (decimal 206)
defining Unicode char U+00CF (decimal 207)
defining Unicode char U+00D0 (decimal 208)
defining Unicode char U+00D1 (decimal 209)
defining Unicode char U+00D2 (decimal 210)
defining Unicode char U+00D3 (decimal 211)
defining Unicode char U+00D4 (decimal 212)
defining Unicode char U+00D5 (decimal 213)
defining Unicode char U+00D6 (decimal 214)
defining Unicode char U+00D8 (decimal 216)
defining Unicode char U+00D9 (decimal 217)
defining Unicode char U+00DA (decimal 218)
defining Unicode char U+00DB (decimal 219)
defining Unicode char U+00DC (decimal 220)
defining Unicode char U+00DD (decimal 221)
defining Unicode char U+00DE (decimal 222)
defining Unicode char U+00DF (decimal 223)
defining Unicode char U+00E0 (decimal 224)
defining Unicode char U+00E1 (decimal 225)
defining Unicode char U+00E2 (decimal 226)
defining Unicode char U+00E3 (decimal 227)
defining Unicode char U+00E4 (decimal 228)
defining Unicode char U+00E5 (decimal 229)
defining Unicode char U+00E6 (decimal 230)
defining Unicode char U+00E7 (decimal 231)
defining Unicode char U+00E8 (decimal 232)
defining Unicode char U+00E9 (decimal 233)
defining Unicode char U+00EA (decimal 234)
defining Unicode char U+00EB (decimal 235)
defining Unicode char U+00EC (decimal 236)
defining Unicode char U+00ED (decimal 237)
defining Unicode char U+00EE (decimal 238)
defining Unicode char U+00EF (decimal 239)
defining Unicode char U+00F0 (decimal 240)
defining Unicode char U+00F1 (decimal 241)
defining Unicode char U+00F2 (decimal 242)
defining Unicode char U+00F3 (decimal 243)
defining Unicode char U+00F4 (decimal 244)
defining Unicode char U+00F5 (decimal 245)
defining Unicode char U+00F6 (decimal 246)
defining Unicode char U+00F8 (decimal 248)
defining Unicode char U+00F9 (decimal 249)
defining Unicode char U+00FA (decimal 250)
defining Unicode char U+00FB (decimal 251)
defining Unicode char U+00FC (decimal 252)
defining Unicode char U+00FD (decimal 253)
defining Unicode char U+00FE (decimal 254)
defining Unicode char U+00FF (decimal 255)
defining Unicode char U+0102 (decimal 258)
defining Unicode char U+0103 (decimal 259)
defining Unicode char U+0104 (decimal 260)
defining Unicode char U+0105 (decimal 261)
defining Unicode char U+0106 (decimal 262)
defining Unicode char U+0107 (decimal 263)
defining Unicode char U+010C (decimal 268)
defining Unicode char U+010D (decimal 269)
defining Unicode char U+010E (decimal 270)
defining Unicode char U+010F (decimal 271)
defining Unicode char U+0110 (decimal 272)
defining Unicode char U+0111 (decimal 273)
defining Unicode char U+0118 (decimal 280)
defining Unicode char U+0119 (decimal 281)
defining Unicode char U+011A (decimal 282)
defining Unicode char U+011B (decimal 283)
defining Unicode char U+011E (decimal 286)
defining Unicode char U+011F (decimal 287)
defining Unicode char U+0130 (decimal 304)
defining Unicode char U+0131 (decimal 305)
defining Unicode char U+0132 (decimal 306)
defining Unicode char U+0133 (decimal 307)
defining Unicode char U+0139 (decimal 313)
defining Unicode char U+013A (decimal 314)
defining Unicode char U+013D (decimal 317)
defining Unicode char U+013E (decimal 318)
defining Unicode char U+0141 (decimal 321)
defining Unicode char U+0142 (decimal 322)
defining Unicode char U+0143 (decimal 323)
defining Unicode char U+0144 (decimal 324)
defining Unicode char U+0147 (decimal 327)
defining Unicode char U+0148 (decimal 328)
defining Unicode char U+014A (decimal 330)
defining Unicode char U+014B (decimal 331)
defining Unicode char U+0150 (decimal 336)
defining Unicode char U+0151 (decimal 337)
defining Unicode char U+0152 (decimal 338)
defining Unicode char U+0153 (decimal 339)
defining Unicode char U+0154 (decimal 340)
defining Unicode char U+0155 (decimal 341)
defining Unicode char U+0158 (decimal 344)
defining Unicode char U+0159 (decimal 345)
defining Unicode char U+015A (decimal 346)
defining Unicode char U+015B (decimal 347)
defining Unicode char U+015E (decimal 350)
defining Unicode char U+015F (decimal 351)
defining Unicode char U+0160 (decimal 352)
defining Unicode char U+0161 (decimal 353)
defining Unicode char U+0162 (decimal 354)
defining Unicode char U+0163 (decimal 355)
defining Unicode char U+0164 (decimal 356)
defining Unicode char U+0165 (decimal 357)
defining Unicode char U+016E (decimal 366)
defining Unicode char U+016F (decimal 367)
defining Unicode char U+0170 (decimal 368)
defining Unicode char U+0171 (decimal 369)
defining Unicode char U+0178 (decimal 376)
defining Unicode char U+0179 (decimal 377)
defining Unicode char U+017A (decimal 378)
defining Unicode char U+017B (decimal 379)
defining Unicode char U+017C (decimal 380)
defining Unicode char U+017D (decimal 381)
defining Unicode char U+017E (decimal 382)
defining Unicode char U+200C (decimal 8204)
defining Unicode char U+2013 (decimal 8211)
defining Unicode char U+2014 (decimal 8212)
defining Unicode char U+2018 (decimal 8216)
defining Unicode char U+2019 (decimal 8217)
defining Unicode char U+201A (decimal 8218)
defining Unicode char U+201C (decimal 8220)
defining Unicode char U+201D (decimal 8221)
defining Unicode char U+201E (decimal 8222)
defining Unicode char U+2030 (decimal 8240)
defining Unicode char U+2031 (decimal 8241)
defining Unicode char U+2039 (decimal 8249)
defining Unicode char U+203A (decimal 8250)
defining Unicode char U+2423 (decimal 9251)
)
Now handling font encoding OT1 ...
... processing UTF-8 mapping file for font encoding OT1
(/usr/local/texlive/2013/texmf-dist/tex/latex/base/ot1enc.dfu
File: ot1enc.dfu 2008/04/05 v1.1m UTF-8 support for inputenc
defining Unicode char U+00A1 (decimal 161)
defining Unicode char U+00A3 (decimal 163)
defining Unicode char U+00B8 (decimal 184)
defining Unicode char U+00BF (decimal 191)
defining Unicode char U+00C5 (decimal 197)
defining Unicode char U+00C6 (decimal 198)
defining Unicode char U+00D8 (decimal 216)
defining Unicode char U+00DF (decimal 223)
defining Unicode char U+00E6 (decimal 230)
defining Unicode char U+00EC (decimal 236)
defining Unicode char U+00ED (decimal 237)
defining Unicode char U+00EE (decimal 238)
defining Unicode char U+00EF (decimal 239)
defining Unicode char U+00F8 (decimal 248)
defining Unicode char U+0131 (decimal 305)
defining Unicode char U+0141 (decimal 321)
defining Unicode char U+0142 (decimal 322)
defining Unicode char U+0152 (decimal 338)
defining Unicode char U+0153 (decimal 339)
defining Unicode char U+2013 (decimal 8211)
defining Unicode char U+2014 (decimal 8212)
defining Unicode char U+2018 (decimal 8216)
defining Unicode char U+2019 (decimal 8217)
defining Unicode char U+201C (decimal 8220)
defining Unicode char U+201D (decimal 8221)
)
Now handling font encoding OMS ...
... processing UTF-8 mapping file for font encoding OMS
(/usr/local/texlive/2013/texmf-dist/tex/latex/base/omsenc.dfu
File: omsenc.dfu 2008/04/05 v1.1m UTF-8 support for inputenc
defining Unicode char U+00A7 (decimal 167)
defining Unicode char U+00B6 (decimal 182)
defining Unicode char U+00B7 (decimal 183)
defining Unicode char U+2020 (decimal 8224)
defining Unicode char U+2021 (decimal 8225)
defining Unicode char U+2022 (decimal 8226)
)
Now handling font encoding OMX ...
... no UTF-8 mapping file for font encoding OMX
Now handling font encoding U ...
... no UTF-8 mapping file for font encoding U
defining Unicode char U+00A9 (decimal 169)
defining Unicode char U+00AA (decimal 170)
defining Unicode char U+00AE (decimal 174)
defining Unicode char U+00BA (decimal 186)
defining Unicode char U+02C6 (decimal 710)
defining Unicode char U+02DC (decimal 732)
defining Unicode char U+200C (decimal 8204)
defining Unicode char U+2026 (decimal 8230)
defining Unicode char U+2122 (decimal 8482)
defining Unicode char U+2423 (decimal 9251)
))
(/usr/local/texlive/2013/texmf-dist/tex/generic/babel/babel.sty
Package: babel 2013/12/03 3.9h The Babel package
(/usr/local/texlive/2013/texmf-dist/tex/generic/babel-norsk/norsk.ldf
Language: norsk 2012/08/06 v2.0i Norsk support from the babel system
(/usr/local/texlive/2013/texmf-dist/tex/generic/babel/babel.def
File: babel.def 2013/12/03 3.9h Babel common definitions
\babel@savecnt=\count88
\U@D=\dimen103
)
Package babel Info: Making " an active character on input line 113.
))
(/usr/local/texlive/2013/texmf-dist/tex/latex/amsfonts/amsfonts.sty
Package: amsfonts 2013/01/14 v3.01 Basic AMSFonts support
\@emptytoks=\toks16
\symAMSa=\mathgroup4
\symAMSb=\mathgroup5
LaTeX Font Info: Overwriting math alphabet `\mathfrak' in version `bold'
(Font) U/euf/m/n --> U/euf/b/n on input line 106.
)
(/usr/local/texlive/2013/texmf-dist/tex/latex/amsfonts/amssymb.sty
Package: amssymb 2013/01/14 v3.01 AMS font symbols
)
(/usr/local/texlive/2013/texmf-dist/tex/latex/amsmath/amsmath.sty
Package: amsmath 2013/01/14 v2.14 AMS math features
\@mathmargin=\skip43
For additional information on amsmath, use the `?' option.
(/usr/local/texlive/2013/texmf-dist/tex/latex/amsmath/amstext.sty
Package: amstext 2000/06/29 v2.01
(/usr/local/texlive/2013/texmf-dist/tex/latex/amsmath/amsgen.sty
File: amsgen.sty 1999/11/30 v2.0
\@emptytoks=\toks17
\ex@=\dimen104
))
(/usr/local/texlive/2013/texmf-dist/tex/latex/amsmath/amsbsy.sty
Package: amsbsy 1999/11/29 v1.2d
\pmbraise@=\dimen105
)
(/usr/local/texlive/2013/texmf-dist/tex/latex/amsmath/amsopn.sty
Package: amsopn 1999/12/14 v2.01 operator names
)
\inf@bad=\count89
LaTeX Info: Redefining \frac on input line 210.
\uproot@=\count90
\leftroot@=\count91
LaTeX Info: Redefining \overline on input line 306.
\classnum@=\count92
\DOTSCASE@=\count93
LaTeX Info: Redefining \ldots on input line 378.
LaTeX Info: Redefining \dots on input line 381.
LaTeX Info: Redefining \cdots on input line 466.
\Mathstrutbox@=\box26
\strutbox@=\box27
\big@size=\dimen106
LaTeX Font Info: Redeclaring font encoding OML on input line 566.
LaTeX Font Info: Redeclaring font encoding OMS on input line 567.
\macc@depth=\count94
\c@MaxMatrixCols=\count95
\dotsspace@=\muskip10
\c@parentequation=\count96
\dspbrk@lvl=\count97
\tag@help=\toks18
\row@=\count98
\column@=\count99
\maxfields@=\count100
\andhelp@=\toks19
\eqnshift@=\dimen107
\alignsep@=\dimen108
\tagshift@=\dimen109
\tagwidth@=\dimen110
\totwidth@=\dimen111
\lineht@=\dimen112
\@envbody=\toks20
\multlinegap=\skip44
\multlinetaggap=\skip45
\mathdisplay@stack=\toks21
LaTeX Info: Redefining \[ on input line 2665.
LaTeX Info: Redefining \] on input line 2666.
)
(/usr/local/texlive/2013/texmf-dist/tex/latex/amscls/amsthm.sty
Package: amsthm 2004/08/06 v2.20
\thm@style=\toks22
\thm@bodyfont=\toks23
\thm@headfont=\toks24
\thm@notefont=\toks25
\thm@headpunct=\toks26
\thm@preskip=\skip46
\thm@postskip=\skip47
\thm@headsep=\skip48
\dth@everypar=\toks27
)
(/home/marius/texmf/tex/latex/mtpro2/mtpro2.sty
Package: mtpro2 2009/4/27 v2.3 MathTimePro II - added arc accents MathTimePro I
I - fixed rbrace problem with straightbraces and morphedbraces options MathTime
Pro II - fix bug with z = \delimiter "026E30F widetilde{\delimiter "026E30F sum
_{x }}MathTimePro II v2 font support (PCTeX/WaS)MathTimePro II v2.1a Allowed al
ternate form of I in Math Script Fonts (MS)
Now handling font encoding LMP1 ...
... no UTF-8 mapping file for font encoding LMP1
Now handling font encoding LMP2 ...
... no UTF-8 mapping file for font encoding LMP2
Now handling font encoding LMP3 ...
... no UTF-8 mapping file for font encoding LMP3
\pointcount@=\count101
\prePbox@=\box28
\Pbox@=\box29
\LRbox@=\box30
\HATbox@=\box31
\TDbox@=\box32
\CHbox@=\box33
\ARCbox@=\box34
\preSbox@=\box35
\Sbox@=\box36
\SQcount@=\count102
\SQRTbox@=\box37
\UPROOT@=\count103
\LEFTROOT@=\count104
\limtype@=\count105
\xlfont@=\count106
\xlposition@=\count107
\xlposition@ii=\count108
\optype@=\count109
\x@count=\count110
\maxXLscripts@=\dimen113
)
No file test.aux.
\openout1 = `test.aux'.
(/usr/local/texlive/2013/texmf-dist/tex/latex/amsfonts/umsa.fd
File: umsa.fd 2013/01/14 v3.01 AMS symbols A
)
(/usr/local/texlive/2013/texmf-dist/tex/latex/amsfonts/umsb.fd
File: umsb.fd 2013/01/14 v3.01 AMS symbols B
) [1
{/usr/local/texlive/2013/texmf-var/fonts/map/pdftex/updmap/pdftex.map}] (./test
.aux) )
Here is how much of TeX's memory you used:
2217 strings out of 493308
24371 string characters out of 6137822
83938 words of memory out of 5000000
5676 multiletter control sequences out of 15000+600000
33819 words of font info for 37 fonts, out of 8000000 for 9000
957 hyphenation exceptions out of 8191
27i,4n,24p,269b,123s stack positions out of 5000i,500n,10000p,200000b,80000s
!pdfTeX error: /usr/local/texlive/2013/bin/x86_64-linux/pdflatex (file mt2sys):
Font mt2sys at 480 not found
==> Fatal error occurred, no output PDF file produced!
```

I am a newbie when it comes to managing tex and texlive, I only use it for typesetting, and I have been unable to learn how to install custom packages etc. I suspect the problem is that the guides require preliminaries which I do not have.

I hope you would be able to swiftly write out a guide to start using mtpro2 on texlive.

Thank you for your time.

Kind regards,

Marius

Comment: You conjecture that "mtpro2 is installed with texlive by default". That's not correct. Due to licensing issues, even the "lite" subset of the full `mtpro2` package (which may be downloaded free of charge from the PCTeX website) is *not* available on the CTAN, let alone distributed with either TeXLive or MikTeX.

Comment: Two additional comments: If you're going to use the `mtpro2` package, don't load the `amssymb` package as well unless you want to get lots of warnings about symbols being redefined. Second, take a look at the posting [Why is `\[ ... \]` preferable to `$$ ... $$`](http://tex.stackexchange.com/q/503/5001) for reasons *not* to use `$$` in LaTeX documents.

Comment: According to your `.log` file, the file `mtpro2.sty` is in `/home/marius/texmf/tex/latex/mtpro2/mtpro2.sty`. The error seems to mean that you didn't install properly the fonts. Try adding `\pdfmapfile{+mtpro2.map}` at the beginning of the `.tex` file.

Comment: Try `updmap --enable Map=mtpro2.map` first.